# Which of the two approaches for REST validation would you prefer?

Tags: java, spring, rest

so basically me and a colleague of mine were arguing which of the following approaches would be better for custom rest validation. Basically the idea is to perform some checks and return response entity, so in case a check fails -> return response entity with chosen status , if not -> response entity (200);

The first approach is more of a functional one, where you give the Validation object the type of Object you want to validate (), add a rule which basically is expecting a predicate, reason message and response entity status (added to List, ResponseEntity>) , goes through all rules, validates if any has failed (in such case return the response enitity with the status of the failed rule) - if no rule failed -> return the consumer from orElseGet which would return a new response entity with status OK. So you can add as many rules as you want and you will have only the one "return" statement.

```
public ResponseEntity(String s){
      return new Validation<String>()
            .addRule(
                    s -> s == null,
                    "string length should not be null",
                    HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST
            )
            .addRule(
                    s -> s.length < 10,
                    "string length should be > 10",
                    HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
            )
            .addRule(
                    s -> s.length > 20,
                    "string length sbould be < 20",
                    HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST
            )
            .collectRules()
            .stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getVal1().test(s))
            .findFirst()
            .map(Tuple::getVal2)
            .orElseGet(() -> {
               //do some computations
                return new ResponseEntity<>("ok", HttpStatus.OK);
            });
}
```

}

The second approach is pretty much more streightforward - no need of explanation, the nok returns new response entity with 400 status and the message you've provided, while ok returns new response entity with status ok.

```
public ResponseEntity(String s){

if({check}) {
        return nok("reason for failure message");
    }

    if({check}) {
        return nok("reason for failure message");
    }

    if({check}) {
        return nok("{reason for failure message}");
    }

    if({check}) {
        return nok("{reason for failure message}");
    }

   //do some computations

    return ok();

}
```

}

So which approach would you prefer to use and why ? :)

Comment: This one is primarily opinion-based. I would pick the first one, but I would somehow improve it.

Comment: I would prefer using standard bean validation, built-in with Spring MVC. When validating directly from the controller, I also prefer throwing an exception, and thus be able to return a value from my method, rather than having to wrap the result in a Response. Annotating the exceptio with ResponseStatus makes Spring return an error response automatically. A ControllerAdvice can be used, too.

Comment: My opinion: #2. Why make it complicated for nothing? What do you gain by using streams and lambda expressions here? (They are not a golden hammer to solve any problem with).